# How can I add new attributes to my rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I created a model using: `rails g model category`
Now I want to add some attributes to that model like a name

so I went to the model and added the line `attribute :name`

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :name
  #has_many :posts
end
```

This is how my Controller looks like:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

  #def permitted_params
   # params.require(:category).permit(:name)
  #end

  def index

  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    #category.create(permitted_params)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def show
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

Then I run the command : `rails db:migrate` and I wanted to add some stuff to my database to test it out.

I used the rails console and tryed to add a category:

[image: Console output]

What do I need to do to write the name into the database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The attribute you're defining in your model is a virtual attribute and will not write anything to the database.

you'll have to define a migration to add columns/attributes to the database.

steps:
1. remove the `attribute :name` from category.rb

2. create a rails migration `rails g migration add_fields_to_categories name:string attribute2:type attribute3:type`
3. run `rails db:migrate`
4. reopen the console and create a new category with name attributes.
5. Now check

Answer (score 1):

To add attribute to Model you should use this command:

```
rails g migration AddNameToCategory name:string
rails db:migrate
```

Comment: Yea I already found this but it adds every time I do this a new migration file. Why its not possible to edit just the 3957934_create_category.rb ? Then I would just have to open one file to see all the tableraws

Comment: no because, thats the purpose of migrations that you can back in a time to some specific db settings. So every time you need to change db add new table, new column it need to be single file  which is tracked for future. So you can delete that migration file and create new by generating with rails g migration ....

Comment: so for now you can delete all migrations in db/migration which are created for adding name to category. and after that create new one with this command I wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

While the rails generator is already creating a database-migration for the attributes you specified, you will need to create a new migration for adding new attributes / database columns. Check out the migration guide:

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

For creating a new migration you can run:

`rails g migration add_categories_name`

inside the migrations change method:

`add_column :categories, :name, :string`

then run `rake db:migrate` again.

Also remove the call to attributes from your model.